Solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\sin\left(t\right)x=\sin\left(2t\right)$
How do I solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\sin\left(t\right)x=\sin\left(2t\right)$?
My try:
$$\mu(t)=\exp\left(\int\sin(t) \mathrm{d}t\right)=\exp(-\cos(t))$$
$$\exp(-\cos(t))\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\sin(t)\exp(-\cos(t))x=\sin(2t)\exp(-\cos(t)).$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\exp(-\cos(t))x\right)=\sin(2t)\exp(-\cos(t))$$
$$\exp(-\cos(t))x=\int\sin(2t)\exp(-\cos(t)) \mathrm{d}t$$
But the integral on RHS looks messy. How do I solve this ODE correctly?

See Wolfram.

Lol why the downvotes bruh, like everyone assumes us here to know answer to every question right?

@Arbatus I too do not understand why anyone would downvote here. It seems to me that you 'did due diligence,' and showed an appropriate amount of work.
